# Passing an array into a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

Consider the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int []); 

int main(void) {
     int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
     swap(a);
     printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
     swap(&a[1]);
     printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
     return 0; 
}

void swap(int x[]) {
     int temp = x[0];
     x[0] = x[1];
     x[1] = temp; 
}
```

Can anyone explain why the following code gives an output
`2 1 3`
`2 3 1`

rather than
`2 1 3`
`1 2 3`

I understand that `swap(a)` swaps `a[0]` and `a[1]`. But I'm not so sure how `swap(&a[1])` works. In both cases we are passing the array `a` into the function `swap`, are we not? So my hypothesis was that `swap(&a[1])` should again swap `a[0]` and `a[1]`, giving us back the original order `2 3 1`.

EDIT: This code was written as intended. I just wanted to see what happens if we pass an address of an element other than the first element into the function. Apparently if I pass `&a[n]` into the function, it disregards all elements before `a[n]` and treats `a[n]` as the first element?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But how exactly does `swap(&a[1])` work? In other words, what is going on when we pass into the function an address that is not the first element? Does it then treat `&a[1]` as the address of the first element?

Comment: change swap(&a[1]) to swap(&a[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swap function takes and address of an integer as input and swaps element at that address with element at next address.

```
swap(a) is same as swap(&a[0])
It will swap element at index 0 with element at index 1.
Now your array becomes {2,1,3}
swap(&a[1]) swaps element at index 1 with element at index 2.
So your array now becomes {2,3,1}
```

Remember when you pass an array actually you are passing address of element at index 0 (`&a[0]`).

Comment: So when I pass `&a[1]` into the function, it treats `&a[1]` as though it was `&a[0]`? Because in the function definition of `swap`, it clearly indicates swapping the elements at index 0 and 1.

Comment: @Vizuna: When you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer. Your function signature is the same as saying `void swap(int *x)`. So the function assumes it has a pointer to at least two consecutive `int` and swaps the values at `*(x+0)` and `*(x+1)`.

Comment: Yes, when you pass `&a[1]` `x[0] is same as a[1]`. Means your `x` (array in `swap` function) starts from index 1 of `a` (array in your `main`)

Comment: @Blastfurnace I see. So if I pass the pointer into the function, it treats the element pointed to as the first element, regardless of its position in the original array?

Comment: @Vizuna: Yes, you must remember that the function doesn't actually see an array type, just a pointer. That's also why you can't determine the "size" of an array parameter, it's already decayed to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you swap first time you sent an array starting with 0 index then it exchanges 0th and 1st index values means at first swap, array becomes {2,1,3} then again you sent this array starting with 1 index means you sent only two values {1,3}, then that values gets exchanges. In this case x[0] = 1 & x[1] = 3, that is why the output came as {2,3,1} here 2 remains as it is.

Answer (score 0):

In the first call `swap(a);` you are passing the entire array (actually a pointer to the first element.) So you are swapping elements 0 and 1, which are 1 and 2, respectively, therefore your first output is `2 1 3`.

In the second call `swap(&a[1]);` you are passing the address of the second element in the array, and in your `swap` function you are therefore swapping the second and third elements, at indices 1 and 2, which are 1 and 3, respectively. That's why your answer after the second iteration is `2 3 1`.

Possibly what you meant was

```
swap(&a[0]);
```

This will swap the values at indices 0 and 1, which will give you the desired output of `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code before the first println statement you are passing a complete array to the parameter of the fuction but in the next you are just passing a single value of location of a[1] which make bit confusing for the function because it has only a single value to swap or it might be as first you passed a zero(0) index or  the array to swap with the next time you pass first 1 index of array to swap with which means [1,3 to swap] so  pass complete in next statment as this

```
 swap(a);
 printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
 swap(a);
 printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
 return 0;
```

this will generate your desire answer